# FND_STADARD_DATE

Tags: oracle-ebs

Can I create my own DATE Value set  and use it in segments?

Because when I create my own DATE Value set, I can't save it on Segments Summary form, can anyone answer me ?

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question

Comment: I don't know the answer off the top of my head, but I don't think the question is that vague for Oracle EBS developers familiar with flex fields.